# Grabbing specific lines from block of TEXT

Tags: xml, grep

I have a large TEXT (XML?) dump and I want to get out just the lines containing my content.

For example, I want the 'TEXT HERE' part grepped out or something.  Is there a way to grep this out throughout the file so I get all 'values' of the 'Content' tags?

```
<mtg:Property displayName="Content" hidden="false" name="content" nullable="true"
readonly="false" type="string">
              <mtg:Value>TEXT HERE</mtg:Value>
</mtg:Property>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths

Comment: Don't parse XML with regex. There are command-line tools to make XPath queries, they'd work better. Also, what's with all the quotes? It doesn't look like valid XML

Comment: Are you sure your file is not valid XML? Then please update the question. In any case the markdown parser won't touch your file sample if you add four spaces at the beginning of the lines. Use the [edit] link to update the question as needed. I edited it to have valid XML

Comment: You edited the description, but not the file sample. Does the sample correspond to what you have? If so, why is it not valid XML?

Comment: The sample does correspond to what I have.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk '/content/ {print $2}' FS='<mtg:Value>' RS='</mtg:Value>'
```

- set record separator to `</mtg:Value>`
- set field separator to `<mtg:Value>`
- find records containing `content` and print field 2